# Set Global Parameters Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony2. For my application I need to set some global parameters for this.

I have defined parameter in my `parameters.ini` file as:

```
#app/config/parameters.ini

[parameters]
    mailer_auth_mode="login"
    user_thumbnail_path="images/user/thumbnail"
```

I am able to access this in my controller with the following code:

```
$this->container->getParameter('user_thumbnail_path');
```

As I am using FOSUserBundle and I have override `ProfileHandler` class and in this class I want to use the parameter but I don't know how.

Comment: In general, you will want to make your "handler" class a service and then inject the parameters in to it.  Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: thx Cerad , but this solution will not fit in my case as i understand because i m beginner in symfony2 ... I have use FOSUserBundle and override its handler class there i want to use this parameter...

Comment: Consider updating your question and making it FOSUserBundle specific.  I don't use the bundle so I can't give you a precise answer.  But plenty of other people use the bundle.  In it's current form, the question is too generic for anyone to offer more than a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own hander or extends the one that you want.

Register it as a service.

```
my.handler:
    class: Acme\MyBundle\Form\Handler\MyHandler
    arguments: ...
```

Then set the service id as the handler for the form you want to handle.

```
fos_user:
    ...
    registration:
        form:
           handler: my.handler
```